# Finding biggest number of collinear points in 3D

Tags: algorithm, optimization, linear-algebra

I was given a task where I have to find a straight line that goes through the most points in a given set (>5000).

I was able to solve the problem with connecting 2 points and checking every other point if it is collinear, but that is an O(N^3) algorithm.

I would like to know if there is a way to make my program run **better than O(N^3)**.

Comment: You can calculate the slope for all pair of points and store them in a structure that is sorted by occurrence of slope. Then just move down the structure calculating the number of colinear points within a slope group until you know for sure that you found the largest set.

Comment: Doesn't this only work in 2D ? I mean doesn't the line defined by P0 an P1 could have the same slope as the line defined by P0 and P2 and not be collinear ?

Comment: Like if P0(0,0,0) P1(3,0,3) P2(0,3,3) the slopes are the same but they are not colinear

Comment: It's not enough to look at just the slope because parallel lines share the same slope. This simply allows you to create groups of slopes; you only need to compare within each group (and not all groups either). You can use this in conjunction with the idea of calculating line equations. This will also be O(N^2 log n), but you need to calculate line equations less often which might shave off a couple cycles at best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in `O(n^2)` by using a hash.

- for each pair of 2 points find the line equation defined by them `O(n^2)`

  - put these equations in a hash `O(1)` (average complexity) in order to count occurrences of each.
- go through all hash equations and find the one with the most count `O(n ^ 2)`. This is the line you are searching for.

Total time complexity of the alg: `O(n^2) * O(1) + O(n^2) = O(n^2)`.

The tricky bit is that the same line can seemingly have 2 different equations due to floating point precision. You need to find a hash function that takes this into account.

---

Another way is to:

- put the equation in a vector `O(n^2)`
- sort the vector `O(n^2 log(n^2) = O(n^2 log n)`
- and then finally find the longest sequence of equal equations `O(n ^ 2)`.

This will have a final complexity of `O(n^2 log n)`.

Comment: You probably don't need to sort the vector, you can just store a hash map keyed by the line parameters, but this won't affect the overall time complexity.

Comment: Sorting a vector of `O(n^2)` lines will take `O(n^2 log n)` time.

Comment: @comingstorm will this make the final complexity `O(n^2 log n)` ?

Comment: If you sort it, yes.  @kevmo314 suggests hashing the line instead of sorting it, which gets you back to `O(n^2)`, but that will only work if you can normalize all equivalent lines to an exact match.

Comment: If you constrain your points to integers (or just scale up your coordinates so they're on the integer lattice), then you can find a parametric vector denoted by (x0, y0, z0, a, b, c), see: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/404446/7354 which will all be integers. Since this isn't a unique representation for a line, just define the unique representation as the one with z0 = 0 and a > 0 or b > 0 or c > 0 and gcd(a, b, c) = 1 so (x0, y0, a, b, c) is sufficient as a hash tuple.

Comment: i forgot to add that output should be the coordinates that are collinear,  does this change anything?

Comment: @user3705008 not much. You keep the 2 points in the same structure as the equation.

Comment: could you please be a little more specific ? I like this approach but im new to c++ and dont know for example how to find the lines with the most occurences.